# Displaying APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON object in Angular throws error

Tags: angular, rx-java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

Hello I have created a new `Spring Boot 2.0` application with `WebFlux` based on. So I have a method which produces `APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON` with `Interval` every 5 seconds. It looks like:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> findAllPeople(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    Flux<Person> personFlux = personRepository.findAll();
    return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON).body(personFlux, Person.class);
}
```

Basically I'd like to attach it to `Angular 4` app with latest `Http Client module`. Now I am struggeling with an error which says:

```
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 49 at JSON.parse 
text:
"{"id":1,"name":"JAN","surname":"NOWAK","age":10}↵{"id":2,"name":"ADAM","surname":"KOWAL","age":20}↵"
```

So as you see I get two `JSONs` and I would like to expose it in browser. I know what does the error mean but how it's possible when I change `MediaType` to regular `Application JSON` it works properly?

At frontend side I have a component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  title = 'app';
  dataGet: any;


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/person').subscribe((res => {
      console.log('------', res);
      this.dataGet = res;
    }));
  }
```

and then I display it

```
<H1>Data get</H1>
<div *ngFor="let d of dataGet">
  {{d.id}}
  {{d.name}}
  {{d.age}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `"application/stream+json"` media type is useful for server to server communication and the browser doesn't know how to parse that: it seems it does not understand that it should consider each JSON object separately and split on new lines.

For server to browser communication, the `"text/event-stream"` (a.k.a. SSE) is probably a better choice.